# Can't mount Android system.img in Mac

Tags: android-source, mount

I downloaded the AOSP source code, and successfully make the build. Now with the new built system.img file, I want to mount it and take a look inside. However I am not be able to mount it. I am working on the MacOS, and the command I used was:

```
$ file system.img
system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=b250775f-0c87-4e48-b8ed-c0443f127ee9 (extents) (large files) (huge files)

$ mount -o loop -t ext4 system.img /mnt
mount: exec /Library/Filesystems/ext4.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_ext4 for /mnt: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Apple doesn't ship a bundled ext4 filesystem.  You'll need to install support for it.  Check into osxfuse+ext4fuse (easily installed via MacPorts or HomeBrew).

Comment: I installed osxfuse and ext4fuse, and use the command: $ ext4fuse system.img sys . and then when I try $ cd sys . it just hangs.

Comment: Actually, the sys folder can be opened in Finder. It just the cd command is not working. The solution works for me. Thanks Perette for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that worked for me

#### Install the required dependencies

```
brew install simg2img
brew install osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse
```

I did a reboot at this stage as it was recommended [here](https://medium.com/@chmodxx/extracting-android-factory-images-on-macos-cc61e45139d1)

#### Convert the system.img into a raw img

```
simg2img system.img system_raw.img
```

#### mount the image

```
mkdir mountpoint
ext4fuse system_raw.img mountpoint
```

At this point you can also browse the img as a folder in Mac Finder

### References

1. https://solumachines.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/mounting-an-android-system-img-on-mac-os-x/
2. https://github.com/anestisb/android-simg2img
3. https://medium.com/@chmodxx/extracting-android-factory-images-on-macos-cc61e45139d1

Answer (score 0):

You can use extfstools to extract the Android `system.img` on macOS and Linux. You don't need root privileges or mount anything.

The original version is at https://github.com/petib/extfstools and it was written for macOS. It doesn't support symlinks.

I have a fork of extfstools at https://github.com/qmfrederik/extfstools which does support symlinks, but was tested on Linux only.